# Inverse of belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got two Models:

- `Order`
- `Invoice`

Each `Order` can have many `Invoice`s - and an `Invoice` can belong to many `Order`s.

So I can search for  an `Order` and check: "Hey, which `Invoices` have been created for this `Order`?"

The other way round each `Invoice` can belong to **multiple** `Order`s, because maybe a customer ordered two products on the same day and so it would be great he'd only get one `Invoice`, which includes both orders.

So this is how I did this:

`Invoice`

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
}
```

`Order`

```
public function invoices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Invoice::class, 'invoice_order');
}
```

This does work - but it does not seem right to change the table to the intermediate table `invoice_order` here. Do you have any thoughts on this? :-)

Thanks in advance for your thoughts :-)

Comment: Do you mean you want to make another model as  InvoiceOrder and make relations? Your relation is perfect what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperating the relation into a seperate pivot table is the commonly used method in laravel (and in most other frameworks) for many to many relationships. 
It's easy to maintain, easy to get related models using many to many relationship, and if someone else needs to work on it in the future, they'll probably have used it in the past as well so wouldn't end up burning their heads.

The other method you could use is to create a json column on one of the tables (you can create on both tables as well if you want, but that's just extra overhead). Then you can store the ids of the related models in this json column. You can then join the tables using the json related commands provided by your database. Eloquent does not support relationships on json, but you can use this package [staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations) to build relationships on json fields.

So overall, I'd suggest keeping a pivot table like the standard way, but if that just won't do, then you can try the json column method